# Sharepoint Designer 2013 Email - Hyperlink Title

Tags: 2013, workflow, hyperlink, sharepoint-designer-workflow, send-email

I currently have a Workflow set up in SharePoint Designer 2013 that sends an email when an item is created.  I wanted to include a link to the specific newly created item in the body of the message.  So, I figured out how to include the Current Item URL for the address, but I don't know how to have the displayed text of the hyperlink reflect the Name of the new item.  Is it possible to have the "Text To Display" show the name of the newly created item?

Thanks everyone,

Chris

Comment: Are you trying to add the link to same item or list item in another list??

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to create a link with display text to the current item on which workflow is running then you can set it up as follow:

[image]

**Steps**:

1. In Email body, select hyperlink option (Pointed as 1 in above image).
2. Then click on ellipses(`...`) next to **Text to display**.
3. Select **Add or Change Lookup** and then set it up like below:

   [image]
4. Similarly, you can set up the link to current item URL by ellipses(`...`) next to **Address**:

   [image]

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  What I'm trying to do is display the text of the hyperlink to reflect the Name of the new item, rather than have it display [%Current Item:Title%].  For example, the users create these travel requests.  I concatenate their First Name, Last Name, and Date of Request to create the unique names.  My workflows send emails to different people based on where the form currently stands.  So I'm wondering if the hyperlink I include in the email can display the name of the new request.

Comment: Yes, then you can create a workflow variable which will store the value by concatenating First Name, Last Name, and Date of Request and then you can use that workflow variable as a Text to display in your hyperlink.

Comment: For that you can use **Set Variable** action in workflow and set its value by concatenation result.